# React: Is this the correct way to create a custom hook? Preventing SWR from unnecessary calls?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, swr

Consider the following:

I'd like to abstract vercel's [conditional swr](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching) hook:

`hooks.js` file

```
import useSWR from 'swr';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import axios from 'axios'

async function getUser(url) {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(url);
    return res;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err ", err);
    if (err.response) {
      const error = await new Error('An error occurred while fetching the data.')
      error.statusText = err.response.statusText;
      error.data = err.response.data.user;
      throw error
    }

    return await res.json()
  }
}

export const fetcher = (url) => getUser(url)


export function useShouldMakeCallToApiUser(shouldMakeCallToApiUser = false) {
  const [shouldMakeCallToApiUser, setShouldMakeCallToApiUser] = useState(shouldMakeCallToApiUser);

  useEffect(() => setShouldMakeCallToApiUser(shouldMakeCallToApiUser), []);

  function useUser(shouldMakeCallToApiUser) {
    const { data: user, error, mutate } = useSWR(shouldMakeCallToApiUser ? '/api/user' : null, fetcher, {
      revalidateOnFocus: false,
      revalidateIfStale: false,
      // revalidateOnReconnect: false, // personally, I didn't need this one
    })

    return {
      user: user?.data?.user,
      isLoading: !error && !user,
      mutate,
      isError: error?.statusText
    }
  }

  return useUser(shouldMakeCallToApiUser);
}
```

In `AuthCheck` file:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useShouldMakeCallToApiUser } from '../../lib/hooks'
import { PageLoader } from '../Loader'


export const AuthCheck = ({ children }) => {

  const router = useRouter()
  const { user, isError } = useShouldMakeCallToApiUser(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && isError === 'Unauthorized') router.push('/');
  }, [isError])

  if (!user) return <PageLoader />// a loading component that prevents the page from rendering

  if (user) {
    return children
  }
}
```

Also, the reason why I made this hook was, I noticed in my app when using the SWR `useUser` without the conditional logic, I would see in the console log requests getting fired to the `/api/user` route.

I figured the above would mitigate this, said another way will this custom hook only fire when the component e.g. function that has it load thus firing the hook?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"Preventing SWR from unnecessary calls"_ - What unnecessary calls are you seeing happening? Setting `revalidateIfStale: false, revalidateOnFocus: false` (or using [`useSWRImmutable`](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation#disable-automatic-revalidations)) should be enough to prevent data revalidation, hence preventing extra requests being made.

Comment: That hook is in my Layout component and in my AuthCheck component respectively. So I’m guessing I’m seeing those logs because those components which have those calls are wrapping the page components, which are causing rerenders?

Comment: Yeah, that would be the case. However, `useSWR` should be caching the response (as long as the `key` param passed to it is the same) and you shouldn't see the request happening every time a re-render happens.

Comment: https://github.com/antonioOrtiz/hillfinder that’s my repo if you don’t mind could you please take a look if you have a moment!

Answer (score 3):

You could simply pass `shouldCallApi` boolean as the prop to the hook `useUser` instead.

```
export function useUser(shouldCallApi) {
    const { data: user, error, mutate } = useSWR(shouldCallApi ? '/api/user' : null, fetcher, {
      revalidateOnFocus: false,
      revalidateIfStale: false,
    })

    return {
      user: user?.data?.user,
      isLoading: !error && !user,
      mutate,
      isError: error?.statusText
    }
  }
}
```

Simply pass the boolean as a prop like this :-

```js
function App() {
   const { ... } = useUser(true);
}
```

Comment: Hi Prateek, I added a question to my original post! Thank you for answering!